# Como validar CPF no lado do cliente com script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando com uma validação de CPF em meu *controller*, porém necessito validar quando o cliente sair do `input` do CPF e então retornar uma mensagem avisando quando o CPF estiver incorreto, através de um `alert` ou algo parecido.

Tentei fazer algo do tipo, mas recebo uma mensagem de erro no console do Chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validarCPF is not definedRelatar:363 onblur

```
<script>
    function validarCPF() {
        if (vercpf(document.frmcpf.cpf.value))
        {
            document.frmcpf.submit();
        } else {
            errors = "1";
            if (errors)
                alert('CPF inválido');
            document.retorno = (errors == '');
        }
    }

    function vercpf(cpf) {
        if (cpf.length != 11 ||
            cpf == "00000000000" ||
            cpf == "11111111111" ||
            cpf == "22222222222" ||
            cpf == "33333333333" ||
            cpf == "44444444444" ||
            cpf == "55555555555" ||
            cpf == "66666666666" ||
            cpf == "77777777777" ||
            cpf == "88888888888" ||
            cpf == "99999999999")
            return false;

        add = 0;

        for (i = 0; i &lt; 9; i++)
                add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (10 - i);
        rev = 11 - (add % 11);
        if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
            rev = 0;
        if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(9)))
            return false;
        add = 0;
                for (i = 0; i &lt; 10; i++)
                add += parseInt(cpf.charAt(i)) * (11 - i);
        rev = 11 - (add % 11);
        if (rev == 10 || rev == 11)
            rev = 0;
        if (rev != parseInt(cpf.charAt(10)))
            return false;
        alert('O CPF INFORMADO É VÁLIDO.');
        return true;
    }

    $j(document).ready(function () {

        $j("#meuForm").validate({
            rules: {
                NrCpf: {NrCpf: true, required: true}
            },
            messages: {
                NrCpf: {NrCpf: alert('CPF Inválido')}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`Input` HTML:

```
<form id="meuform">
    <input type="text" data-id="NrCpf" disabled name="NrCpf" id="NrCpf" class="form-control" onblur="javascript: validarCPF(this.value);" maxlength="14">
</form>
```

Alguém já precisou fazer algo do tipo, ou teria alguma ideia de como me ajudar?

Comment: Este link mostra como validar um CPF enquanto a pessoa esta digitando-o http://www.tutsup.com/2014/11/17/como-validar-cpf-e-cnpj-com-javascript-ou-jquery/ . Acho que é isto que procura

Comment: O script foi declarado *antes* do `input`?

Comment: @Eduardo eu fiz o download do projeto no site, mas o mesmo está com um erro na linha **   if ( valida_cpf_cnpj( cpf_cnpj ) ) {** e não está funcionando aqui.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro não, eu apenas inverti a ordem do post. O script está em aquivo JS separado, eu apenas juntei para postar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seu código não funciona por muitos motivos, entre eles, quando você copiou o source vieram algumas tags como entities, as tags do for vieram assim "&lt" "&gt", tem um "j" voador servindo de Jquery(document.., se você quer uma alternativa continue lendo.

[Gerador e validador de CPF](http://tiagoporto.github.io/gerador-validador-cpf/)

Para validar basta usar essa linha:

```
CPF.valida("123.456.789-00");
```

A lib já filtra pontos e traços.

[Veja no Github](https://github.com/tiagoporto/gerador-validador-cpf)

### Exemplo de utilização

```js
/*!
* Gerador e Validador de CPF v1.0.0
* https://github.com/tiagoporto/gerador-validador-cpf
* Copyright (c) 2014-2015 Tiago Porto (http://www.tiagoporto.com)
* Released under the MIT license
*/
function CPF(){"user_strict";function r(r){for(var t=null,n=0;9>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(10-n);var i=t%11;return i=2>i?0:11-i}function t(r){for(var t=null,n=0;10>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(11-n);var i=t%11;return i=2>i?0:11-i}var n="CPF Inválido",i="CPF Válido";this.gera=function(){for(var n="",i=0;9>i;++i)n+=Math.floor(9*Math.random())+"";var o=r(n),a=n+"-"+o+t(n+""+o);return a},this.valida=function(o){for(var a=o.replace(/\D/g,""),u=a.substring(0,9),f=a.substring(9,11),v=0;10>v;v++)if(""+u+f==""+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v)return n;var c=r(u),e=t(u+""+c);return f.toString()===c.toString()+e.toString()?i:n}}



   var CPF = new CPF();
   document.write(CPF.valida("123.456.789-00"));
   
   document.write("<br> Utilizando o proprio gerador da lib<br><br><br>");
   for(var i =0;i<40;i++) {
      var temp_cpf = CPF.gera();
      document.write(temp_cpf+" = "+CPF.valida(temp_cpf)+"<br>");
   }

$("#input").keypress(function(){
    $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});

$("#input").blur(function(){
     $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input" /><span id="resposta"></span><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Eu verifiquei este, porém necessito de uma para validação em tempo real, ou seja, assim que o usuário sair do input.

Comment: execute o script novamente, coloquei um evento monitorando a tecla pressionada e a saída do focus

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso.

Answer (score 11):

Adaptei o script da resposta do [@AlbertBitencourt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99313/14213).

Removendo a parte que considera `10` e `11` como `0`, pois aparentemente essa validação não existe.

```js
function cpf(cpf){
    cpf = cpf.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if(cpf.toString().length != 11 || /^(\d)\1{10}$/.test(cpf)) return false;
    var result = true;
    [9,10].forEach(function(j){
        var soma = 0, r;
        cpf.split(/(?=)/).splice(0,j).forEach(function(e, i){
            soma += parseInt(e) * ((j+2)-(i+1));
        });
        r = soma % 11;
        r = (r <2)?0:11-r;
        if(r != cpf.substring(j, j+1)) result = false;
    });
    return result;
}

console.log('11111111111', cpf('11111111111'));
console.log('82312321312', cpf('82312321312'));
console.log('825.566.405-02', cpf('825.566.405-02'));
console.log('875.189.681-85', cpf('875.189.681-85'));
console.log('875.189.681-86', cpf('875.189.681-86'));
console.log('640.422.216-70', cpf('640.422.216-70'));
```

#### Links Relacionados

[Como validar e calcular o dígito de controle de um CPF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64608/14213)
[Fórmula para gerar CPF's Válidos](http://www.geradorcpfvalido.com.br/formula-para-gerar-cpf)

Answer (score 4):

Montei uma pseudo classe em JavaScript para gerar e validar números de CPF, seguindo a regra dos dígitos verificadores. O código fonte pode ser encontrado no GitHub:

- https://github.com/tome-vilela/geracpf

Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
var n = new CPF().generate();

if (new CPF().validate(n)) {
  alert('sucesso!');
}
```

Caso precise criar números de CPF para teste, deixei disponível o mesmo algoritmo neste site estático:

- [Gerador de CPF](http://geracpf.com/)

Vale ressaltar que os números gerados são válidos, mas não são reais, a não ser que ocorra uma colisão de um número aleatório com um número real.

Para saber se um número de CPF é real, só consultando a Receita Federal mesmo, mas será necessário informar também a data de nascimento do portador do CPF:

- www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/aplicacoes/atcta/cpf/ConsultaPublica.asp

Finalmente, havendo necessidade de validação automática de um grande número de CPFs recomendo o seguinte Web Service:

- www.soawebservices.com.br

Até o momento foi o mais barato que encontrei, suporta HTTPS e tem disponibilidade razoável (de vez em quando ele sofre de problemas de "timeout").

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz uma em javascript usando o algoritmo da receita federal.

O método recebe uma string sem pontos e traços e retorna um bool se é valido ou não.

```
function VerificaCPF(strCpf) {

var soma;
var resto;
soma = 0;
if (strCpf == "00000000000") {
    return false;
}

for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
}

resto = soma % 11;

if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
    resto = 0;
} else {
    resto = 11 - resto;
}

if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(9, 10))) {
    return false;
}

soma = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
}
resto = soma % 11;

if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
    resto = 0;
} else {
    resto = 11 - resto;
}

if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(10, 11))) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Diversos valores fornecidos pelo site https://www.geradordecpf.org/ não passam no seu algoritmo :(