# Como validar e calcular o dígito de controle de um CPF

Tags: python, algoritmo, validação, brasil

Como funciona o algoritmo que calcula o dígito de um CPF (Cadastro da Pessoa Física brasileiro)? E como esse cálculo é usado para validar o CPF? Se possível, gostaria de exemplos em Python.

Comment: Você pode validar cpf/cnpj usando o código deste repositório no github :https://github.com/rafahlobo/cpfValidator

Answer (score 11):

Uma solução mais [*pythonica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878) seria:

```
def validate(cpf: str) -> bool:

    """ Efetua a validação do CPF, tanto formatação quando dígito verificadores.

    Parâmetros:
        cpf (str): CPF a ser validado

    Retorno:
        bool:
            - Falso, quando o CPF não possuir o formato 999.999.999-99;
            - Falso, quando o CPF não possuir 11 caracteres numéricos;
            - Falso, quando os dígitos verificadores forem inválidos;
            - Verdadeiro, caso contrário.

    Exemplos:

    >>> validate('529.982.247-25')
    True
    >>> validate('52998224725')
    False
    >>> validate('111.111.111-11')
    False
    """

    # Verifica a formatação do CPF
    if not re.match(r'\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}', cpf):
        return False

    # Obtém apenas os números do CPF, ignorando pontuações
    numbers = [int(digit) for digit in cpf if digit.isdigit()]

    # Verifica se o CPF possui 11 números ou se todos são iguais:
    if len(numbers) != 11 or len(set(numbers)) == 1:
        return False

    # Validação do primeiro dígito verificador:
    sum_of_products = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(numbers[0:9], range(10, 1, -1)))
    expected_digit = (sum_of_products * 10 % 11) % 10
    if numbers[9] != expected_digit:
        return False

    # Validação do segundo dígito verificador:
    sum_of_products = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(numbers[0:10], range(11, 1, -1)))
    expected_digit = (sum_of_products * 10 % 11) % 10
    if numbers[10] != expected_digit:
        return False

    return True
```

A lógica implementada é exatamente a mesma descrita nas outras respostas, porém faz uso de ferramentas da linguagem para simplificar a solução.

Comment: Comentando numa resposta velha, mas a observação é pertinente. Você não precisa testar `len(numbers) != 11` pois isso nunca acontecerá, o regex do `if` acima só permite uma string com 11 números e no formato específico. É redundante. Era isso dindo :D

Comment: @fernandosavio Acredito que no dia eu achei que não tendo o ^ e $ na regex poderia pegar o CPF no meio da string. My bad xD

Comment: A observação do `^$` é boa, pode dar problema mesmo. Melhor deixar como está, vou deixar meu comentário, caso ilumine algum ser terreno.

Comment: `match` [sempre procura no início da string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) então se o CPF está no meio da string, [só vai ser encontrado se usar `search`](https://ideone.com/UGO4Sq). @fernandosavio De qq forma, a regex sem `$` [pode pegar dígitos a mais no final](https://ideone.com/5wY1PH). Então ou usa `^` e `$`, ou usa o `if len == 11` (mas prefiro usar `$` pois aí já testa o tamanho de uma vez)

Comment: Ficou mais bonita sua solução `len(set(numbers))` boa! Valeu @Woss

Answer (score 6):

## Como funciona o algoritmo que calcula o dígito de um CPF (Cadastro da Pessoa Física brasileiro)?

[Conforme a resposta do Wilson Neto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66964/2999), [há uma explicação neste link](http://www.geradorcpfvalido.com.br/formula-para-gerar-cpf). Basicamente é aplicado o Módulo 11 em um número de 9 dígitos para gerar o primeiro dígito verificador. O segundo dígito verificador é gerado a partir dos 9 números originais, mais o primeiro dígito verificador.

## E como esse cálculo é usado para validar o CPF?

A validação do CPF é idêntica à geração do CPF. A partir dos 9 primeiros números, são gerados os dois dígitos verificadores. Se forem iguais à entrada fornecida, o CPF é valido.

## Se possível, gostaria de exemplos em Python.

Segue código para validação de CPF em Python.

[O link original está aqui](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Validador-de-CPF-1).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Djames Suhanko
import sys
try:
 cpflimpo=sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
 print "Use %s NUMERO_DO_CPF" % sys.argv[0]
 sys.exit()

if (len(cpflimpo) != 11 or not cpflimpo.isdigit()):
 print "Formato errado. Tente de novo (apenas numeros)"
 sys.exit()

digito = {}
digito[0] = 0
digito[1] = 0
a=10
total=0
for c in range(0,2):
 for i in range(0,(8+c+1)):
  total=total+int(cpflimpo[i])*a
  a=a-1
 digito[c]=int(11-(total%11))
 a=11
 total=0
if (int(cpflimpo[9]) == int(digito[0]) and int(cpflimpo[10]) == int(digito[1])):
 print "CPF valido: ",
 for i in (range(len(cpflimpo))):
   if (i == 2 or i == 5):
    sep=cpflimpo[i]+" ."
   elif (i == 8):
    sep=cpflimpo[i]+" -"
   else:
    sep=cpflimpo[i]
   print "%s" % sep,
else:
 print "CPF invalido"
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo que tanto pode ser utilizado na linha de comando quanto como uma biblioteca Python, com doctests.

```
import re


def validar_cpf(cpf):
    """
    Retorna o CPF válido sanitizado ou False.

    # CPFs corretos
    >>> validar_cpf('123.456.789-09')
    '12345678909'
    >>> validar_cpf('98765432100')
    '98765432100'
    >>> validar_cpf(' 123 123 123 87 ')
    '12312312387'

    # CPFs incorretos
    >>> validar_cpf('12345678900')
    False
    >>> validar_cpf('1234567890')
    False
    >>> validar_cpf('')
    False
    >>> validar_cpf(None)
    False
    """
    cpf = ''.join(re.findall(r'\d', str(cpf)))

    if not cpf or len(cpf) < 11:
        return False

    antigo = [int(d) for d in cpf]

    # Gera CPF com novos dígitos verificadores e compara com CPF informado
    novo = antigo[:9]
    while len(novo) < 11:
        resto = sum([v * (len(novo) + 1 - i) for i, v in enumerate(novo)]) % 11

        digito_verificador = 0 if resto <= 1 else 11 - resto

        novo.append(digito_verificador)

    if novo == antigo:
        return cpf

    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Uso: {} [CPF]".format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        cpf = validar_cpf(sys.argv[1])
        print(cpf if cpf else "CPF Inválido")
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo de código retirado da biblioteca [BRADocs4Py](https://github.com/namio/BRADocs4Py):

```
import re

from itertools import chain

class ValidadorCpf(object):

    def __validarCpf(self, arg):  # type: (CPF) -> bool
        return self.__validarStr(arg.rawValue)

    def __validarStr(self, arg):  # type: (str) -> bool

        if arg == None:
            return False

        p = re.compile('[^0-9]')
        x = p.sub('', arg)

        if len(x) != 11 or len(set(x)) == 1: return False

        return all(self.__hashdigit(x, i + 10) == int(v) for i, v in enumerate(x[9:]))


    def __hashdigit(self, cpf, position):  # type: (str, int) -> int
        """
        Will compute the given `position` checksum digit for the `cpf` input. The input needs to contain all
        elements previous to `position` else computation will yield the wrong result.
        """

        val = sum(int(digit) * weight for digit, weight in zip(cpf, range(position, 1, -1))) % 11

        return 0 if val < 2 else 11 - val

    @staticmethod
    def validar(arg):  # type: (CPF) -> bool or  type: (str) -> bool
        v = ValidadorCpf()

        if type(arg) == CPF: return v.__validarCpf(arg)

        if type(arg) == str: return v.__validarStr(arg)

        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ponto = '.'
traco = '-'
contador = 10
posicao = 0
acumulo = 0
resto = 0
cont = 11
pos = 0
res = 0
acu = 0
cpf = str(input('Digite seu CPF, sem traços e pontos: ')).strip()

if len(cpf) == 11 and cpf.isnumeric():
    cpf_formatado = cpf[0:3] + ponto + cpf[3:6] + ponto + cpf[6:9] + traco + cpf[9:]
    print(f'O CPF informado foi: {cpf_formatado}')

    for i in range(len(cpf[0:9])):
        primeiro = int(cpf[posicao]) * contador
        posicao += 1
        contador -= 1  
        acumulo = acumulo + primeiro

        if contador < 2 and posicao > 8:
            resto = acumulo % 11
            primeiro_verificador = 11 - resto
            if primeiro_verificador >= 10:
                primeiro_verificador = 0
            print(f'Este é o primeiro dígito verificador de seu CPF: {primeiro_verificador}')

    
    for x in range(len(cpf[0:10])):
        segundo = int(cpf[pos]) * cont
        pos += 1
        cont -= 1  
        acu = acu + segundo

        if cont < 2 and pos > 9:
            res = acu % 11
            segundo_verificador = 11 - res
            if segundo_verificador >= 10:
                segundo_verificador = 0
            print(f'Este é o segundo dígito verificador de seu CPF: {segundo_verificador}')

    primeiro_verificador = str(primeiro_verificador)
    segundo_verificador = str(segundo_verificador)

    if primeiro_verificador == cpf[9] and segundo_verificador == cpf[10]:
        print('O CPF foi analisado e aprovado. CPF válido!')

    else:
        print('CPF inválido!')

elif len(cpf) == 14 and '.' == cpf[3] and '.' == cpf[7] and '-' == cpf[11]:
    print(f'O CPF informado foi: {cpf}')
    cpf = cpf.replace('.', '')
    cpf = cpf.replace('-', '')

    for i in range(len(cpf[0:9])):
        primeiro = int(cpf[posicao]) * contador
        posicao += 1
        contador -= 1  
        acumulo = acumulo + primeiro

        if contador < 2 and posicao > 8:
            resto = acumulo % 11
            primeiro_verificador = 11 - resto
            if primeiro_verificador >= 10:
                primeiro_verificador = 0
            print(f'Este é o primeiro dígito verificador de seu CPF: {primeiro_verificador}')

    
    for x in range(len(cpf[0:10])):
        segundo = int(cpf[pos]) * cont
        pos += 1
        cont -= 1  
        acu = acu + segundo

        if cont < 2 and pos > 9:
            res = acu % 11
            segundo_verificador = 11 - res
            if segundo_verificador >= 10:
                segundo_verificador = 0
            print(f'Este é o segundo dígito verificador de seu CPF: {segundo_verificador}')

    primeiro_verificador = str(primeiro_verificador)
    segundo_verificador = str(segundo_verificador)

    if primeiro_verificador == cpf[9] and segundo_verificador == cpf[10]:
        print('O CPF foi analisado e aprovado. CPF válido!')

    else:
        print('CPF inválido!')
                               
else:
    print('CPF inválido!')
```

Answer (score -4):

Biblioteca para validação de CPF ou CNPJ utilizando os digitos verificadores para conferência.

validdocbr

```
pip install validdocbr
pip3 instal validdocbr
```

Utilização

```py
from validdocbr import validdocbr

validador = validdocbr.validdocbr()

validador.cpf('12345678912')   
validador.cnpj =('12345678904321')
```

Retorna True se documento for válido ou False se for inválido.

https://pypi.org/project/validdocbr/

Comment: O autor da pergunta não quer simplesmente validar um *CPF* ele quer saber como funciona o algorítimo de validação para que possa validar um *CPF* sem depender de um pacote ou módulo de terceiros