# Colocar só uma vez o print de mensagem correcta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou a fazer este programa:

> Desenvolva um programa que solicite a digitação de um número de CPF
>   no formato `xxx.xxx.xxx-xx` e indique se é um número válido ou inválido através da 
>   validação dos dígitos verificadores e dos caracteres de formatação.

O código é este:

```
pf = input("CPF(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :") #3 7 11

for letra in cpf:
    if(cpf[3] !=".") or (cpf[7] !=".") or (cpf[11] !="-"):
        cpf = input("O 'CPF' pricisa estar no formato (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :")
    else:
        print("O 'CPF' está no formato correto")
```

Mas quando mando correr a saída é esta:

```
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
O 'CPF' está no formato correto
```

Como posso meter só a sair uma vez?

Answer (score 1):

Não precisas fazer o loop ai. Como já estás a verificar os caracteres `.` e `-` usando as posições do string (e.g `cpf[3] != ""`), o ciclo parece desnecessário.

```
cpf = input("CPF(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :") #3 7 11

if(cpf[3] !=".") or (cpf[7] !=".") or (cpf[11] !="-"):
    cpf = input("O 'CPF' pricisa estar no formato (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :")
else:
    print("O 'CPF' está no formato correto")
```

Comment: Desse modo, o sistema iria solicitar o CPF novamente apenas uma vez, tente trocar o if por while

Comment: Na verdade a verificação do CPF vai além disso. Os dois últimos dígitos são os dígitos verificadores e [é necessário validá-los](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/algoritmo-para-validar-cpf/).

Comment: @NathanSchroeder percebo, sim, faz mais sentido então ser um `while` até a validação passar.
@AndersonCarlosWoss Não estou familiarizado com o CPF, mas percebo a validação que é necessária. Usei apenas o exemplo do código original.

Comment: Aliás, para sua solução a entrada `...........-..` seria um CPF válido: https://ideone.com/JktKch

Comment: Verdade! Eu nem confirmei se o código estava a validar correctamente, reparei só que a causa da repetição era do ciclo por cada letra, mas que depois nem era usado correctamente. Apesar de tudo, votei na resposta com a solução mais apropriada, esta nem sei porque tem um upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Você está percorrendo cada caractere do CPF informado e exibindo a mensagem para cada um. Se o CPF tiver 14 caracteres, aparecerão 14 vezes a mensagem. Isso nem faz sentido fazer. Além, a validação do CPF vai muito além de apenas verificar a formatação. Os dois últimos dígitos são verificadores e você precisa validá-los. Veja:

- [Algoritmo para Validar CPF](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/algoritmo-para-validar-cpf/)
- [Como validar e calcular o dígito de controle de um CPF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64608/5878)

Assim, o que você precisa fazer é algo como:

```
try:
    cpf = input('Informe o CPF: ')
    assert validate(cpf), 'O CPF informado não é válido'
    print('CPF válido')
except AssertionError as error:
    print(error)
```

Onde a função `validate` validará os dígitos verificadores:

```
def validate(cpf: str) -> bool:

    """ Efetua a validação do CPF, tanto formatação quanto dígitos verificadores.

    Parâmetros:
        cpf (str): CPF a ser validado

    Retorno:
        bool:
            - Falso, quando o CPF não possuir o formato 999.999.999-99;
            - Falso, quando o CPF não possuir 11 caracteres numéricos;
            - Falso, quando os dígitos verificadores forem inválidos;
            - Verdadeiro, caso contrário.

    Exemplos:

    >>> validate('529.982.247-25')
    True
    >>> validate('52998224725')
    False
    >>> validate('111.111.111-11')
    False
    """

    # Verifica a formatação do CPF
    if not re.match(r'\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}', cpf):
        return False

    # Obtém apenas os números do CPF, ignorando pontuações
    numbers = [int(digit) for digit in cpf if digit.isdigit()]

    # Verifica se o CPF possui 11 números:
    if len(numbers) != 11:
        return False

    # Validação do primeiro dígito verificador:
    sum_of_products = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(numbers[0:9], range(10, 1, -1)))
    expected_digit = (sum_of_products * 10 % 11) % 10
    if numbers[9] != expected_digit:
        return False

    # Validação do segundo dígito verificador:
    sum_of_products = sum(a*b for a, b in zip(numbers[0:10], range(11, 1, -1)))
    expected_digit = (sum_of_products * 10 % 11) % 10
    if numbers[10] != expected_digit:
        return False

    return True
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GlumKaleidoscopicInfinity) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/QSxBML)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Cara, eu faria o seguinte (eu sou iniciante também, não sei se é o melhor jeito):

```
cpf = input("CPF(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :") #3 7 11

correto = False

for letra in cpf:
    if(cpf[3] !=".") or (cpf[7] !=".") or (cpf[11] !="-"):
        cpf = input("O 'CPF' pricisa estar no formato (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :")
    else:
        correto = True

if correto == True:
     print("O 'CPF' está no formato correto")
```

Comment: Correto, esse código funciona, só necessita acrescentar um verificador para os números do CPF, para validar se não são letras, pois assim, o programa iria aceitar uma resposta como: foo.bar.abc-de

Comment: Na verdade a verificação do CPF vai além disso. Os dois últimos dígitos são os dígitos verificadores e [é necessário validá-los](https://dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/algoritmo-para-validar-cpf/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela informação @AndersonCarlosWoss , não tinha conhecimento

Comment: @IamZack Não faz sentido você percorrer todos os dígitos do CPF, então esse laço de repetição é desnecessário. Um indicativo disso é você nem ter usado o objeto `letra` dentro do laço.

Answer (score -1):

Em seu código, para cada caracter correto, ele faz o print, por esse motivo, o programa deve dar print somente quando o CPF inteiro ter sido validado, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
def verificarNumeros(cpf): #FUNÇÃO QUE IRÁ VERIFICAR SE TODOS OS CARACTERES DO CPF, QUE NÃO SÃO "." NEM "-" SÃO NÚMEROS
    for posicao,caractere in enumerate(cpf): #PARA CADA ELEMENTO DENTRO DE cpf E SUA POSIÇÃO NA STRING
        if posicao!=3 and posicao!=7 and posicao!=11 and not caractere.isdigit(): #VERIFICANDO SE O CARÁCTER NÃO É UM NÚMERO
            return True #SE UM CARÁCTER NÃO FOR UM NÚMERO, ESSA FUNÇÃO IRÁ PARAR E RETORNAR UM VALOR "True" PARA O while DE VERIFICAÇÃO
    return False #CASO NÃO ENCONTRE NENHUM ERRO, IRÁ RETORNAR "False" PARA O while

cpf = input("CPF(xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :") #3 7 11

while verificarNumeros(cpf) or cpf[3] !="." or cpf[7] !="." or cpf[11] !="-": #ENQUANTO O CPF NÃO FOR VÁLIDO, ELE IRÁ PERGUNTAR NOVAMENTE, POIS DO MODO QUE VOCÊ ESTAVA FAZENDO, ELE IRIA PERGUNTAR APENAS 13 VEZES, QUE É A QUANTIDADE DE ELEMENTOS DENTRO DE cpf, OU SEJA, SE O USUÁRIO INSISTISSE 14 VEZES NO ERRO, O PROGRAMA IRIA ACEITAR
    cpf = input("O 'CPF' pricisa estar no formato (xxx.xxx.xxx-xx) :")

print("O 'CPF' está no formato correto") #O PROGRAMA SÓ IRÁ CAIR AQUI QUANDO TODAS AS CONDIÇÕES DO WHILE FOREM FALSAS.
```