# Como executar uma função diversas vezes simultaneamente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que meu código faz:

```
import time

def oi():
    while True:
        print("oi")
        time.sleep(1)

oi()
```

Output (em 2 segundos passados):

```
oi
oi
```

O que quero que faça:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def oi():
    while True:
        print("oi")
        time.sleep(1)

quantidadeDeProcessos = 3

multiprocess(quantidadeDeProcessos, oi())
```

Output (em 2 segundos passados):

```
oi
oi
oi
oi
oi
oi
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Existe alguma relação desta pergunta com a [Como acelerar meu programa em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/369591/5878) Se sim, usaria isso para fazer chamadas HTTP de forma paralela?

Comment: não, gostaria apenas de saber se é possivel fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma maneira usando o modulo threading:

```
import threading
import time

def a():
    while True:
        print("oi")
        time.sleep(1)

numeroDeProcessos = 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(numeroDeProcessos):
        threading.Thread(target=a).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de se fazer isso é simplesmente multiplicando o tanto de "oi's" pelo número de processos:

```py
from time import sleep

def oi(num_process):
    while True:
        print('oi\n' * num_process)
        sleep(1)

oi(3)
```

O output será algo assim (no intervalo de 2 segundos):

```
oi
oi
oi

oi
oi
oi
```

Comment: porem essa função que eu disse foi só um exemplo, queria um modo que funcionasse com qualquer tipo de função

Comment: @x8ss, mas isso funcionaria com qualquer tipo de string digitada. O que você realmente quer? Exemplifique melhor sua pergunta :)