# Remover CPFs no final da página do JavaScript que valida CPF

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando esse script abaixo para validar o CPF que foi obtido [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51342/14262). 
Porém, no final da página do formulário, ele vai gravando no rodapé, os CPFs testados. Como retiro essa função e deixo só a validação?

```js
function CPF() {
  "user_strict";

  function r(r) {
    for (
      var t = null, n = 0; 9 > n; ++n) t += r.toString().charAt(n) * (10 - n);
    var i = t % 11;
    return i = 2 > i ? 0 : 11 - i
  }

  function t(r) {
    for (
      var t = null, n = 0; 10 > n; ++n) t += r.toString().charAt(n) * (11 - n);
    var i = t % 11;
    return i = 2 > i ? 0 : 11 - i
  }
  var n = "CPF Inválido",
    i = "CPF Válido";
  this.gera =
    function() {
      for (
        var n = "", i = 0; 9 > i; ++i) n += Math.floor(9 * Math.random()) + "";
      var o = r(n),
        a = n + "-" + o + t(n + "" + o);
      return a
    }, this.valida =
    function(o) {
      for (
        var a = o.replace(/\D/g, ""), u = a.substring(0, 9), f = a.substring(9, 11), v = 0; 10 > v; v++)
        if ("" + u + f == "" + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v)
          return n;
      var c = r(u),
        e = t(u + "" + c);
      return f.toString() === c.toString() + e.toString() ? i : n
    }
}
var CPF = new CPF();
document.write(CPF.valida("123.456.789-00"));
document.write("<br> Utilizando o proprio gerador da lib<br><br><br>");
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  var temp_cpf = CPF.gera();
  document.write(temp_cpf + " = " + CPF.valida(temp_cpf) + "<br>");
}

$("#input").keypress(function() {
  $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});

$("#input").blur(function() {
  $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" name="input">
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

Comment: Remova  $("#input").keypress(function(){
                            $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
                        });

                        $("#input").blur(function(){
                            $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
                        });

Comment: Função copiada [daqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51342/14262) :)

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5769/132

Answer (score 2):

Retira o final do script, essa parte:

```
$("#input").keypress(function(){
    $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
 });

$("#input").blur(function(){
    $("#resposta").html(CPF.valida($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: Dessa forma ele para de validar. Então comentei as linhas "document.write" e ficou como eu precisava. obrigada !!!