# Habilitar botão submit se CPF for válido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizei a dica desse [link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51340/como-validar-cpf-no-lado-do-cliente-com-script). Porém estou tentando implementar algo a mais que estou precisando e não consigo.

Seguinte: Preciso testar se o cpf é valido e se ele for, libero o botão cadastrar. Para isso testo o cpf com o botão cadastrar modo disable e se for válido troco a condição conforme o código abaixo que não funciona e não sei pq.

```
   <form>
     <p><input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf"/><span id="resposta"></span></p>
     <p><input id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" disabled /></p>
   </form>

   <script>
    function CPF(){"user_strict";function r(r){for(var t=null,n=0;9>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(10-n);var i=t%11;return i=2>i?0:11-i}function t(r){for(var t=null,n=0;10>n;++n)t+=r.toString().charAt(n)*(11-n);var i=t%11;return i=2>i?0:11-i}var n="CPF Inválido",i="CPF Válido";this.gera=function(){for(var n="",i=0;9>i;++i)n+=Math.floor(9*Math.random())+"";var o=r(n),a=n+"-"+o+t(n+""+o);return a},this.valida=function(o){for(var a=o.replace(/\D/g,""),u=a.substring(0,9),f=a.substring(9,11),v=0;10>v;v++)if(""+u+f==""+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v+v)return n;var c=r(u),e=t(u+""+c);return f.toString()===c.toString()+e.toString()?i:n}}

    var CPF = new CPF();

    $(document).ready(function(){   
      $("#cpf").keypress(function(){
      var teste= CPF.valida($(this).val());
      $("#resposta").html(teste);
        if(teste == "CPF Válido"){ 
           $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }else {
          alert("O campo cpf é inválido! Preencha com um CPF válido por favor.");
          return false;
     }
   });

     $("#cpf").blur(function(){
     var teste= CPF.valida($(this).val());
     $("#resposta").html(teste);
        if(teste == "CPF Válido"){ 
           $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
           alert("O campo cpf é inválido! Preencha com um CPF válido por favor.");
          return false;
        } 
      });
    });
  </script>
```

O que retorna da função é uma string correto? CPF Válido ou CPF Inválido. Porém não habilita o botão de jeito nenhum. Testei até recebendo o valor da função e jogando numa variável como está acima no código.

Testei convertendo essa variável para string  ( `tostring(teste)` ).
Definitivamente não sei o que está incorreto uma vez que testar o cpf está ok e quando o mesmo fica válido não troca a condição do botão input submit para enable!

Comment: Pode substituir esses blocos condicionais por `$("#cadastrar").attr("disabled", teste ==  'CPF Inválido');` **:)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque `.keypress` por `.keyup` que funcionará melhor.
Remova return false, senão nunca conseguirá digitar um valor, ainda mais com um `alert` atrapalhando a digitação.

```
$("#cpf").keyup(function(){
     var teste = CPF.valida($(this).val());
     $("#resposta").html(teste);
     if(teste == "CPF Válido"){ 
        $("#cadastrar").removeAttr("disabled");
     }else {    
        $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled",true);
     }
});
```

No .blur somente fazer uma adequação, conforme citei acima.

```
$("#cpf").blur(function(){
     var teste= CPF.valida($(this).val());
     $("#resposta").html(teste);
     if(teste == "CPF Válido"){ 
        $("#cadastrar").removeAttr("disabled");
     } else {
        $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled",true);
     } 
});
```

Não existe o identificador `#submit`, o identificador correto para o botão de submit é `#cadastrar`.

Exemplo funcionando em https://jsfiddle.net/sqpt8pbw/

Comment: Obrigado... exatamente o que estava precisando e não enxergava a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Vou realizar algumas pequenas alterações em seu código.

Ao invés de retornar uma `string` para validar o CPF, eu alterei para retornar um valor booleano (true/false). Desta forma, você apenas faz a comparação normalmente.

Em segundo, remova o `return false` false de seu código, desta forma a pessoa poderá concluir o `CPF`.

Altere o `keypress` para `keyup`. [Veja a diferença entre eles nesta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68941/20615)

E por fim, mas não menos importante, você está utilizando o ID `submit`, mas seu botão está com o ID 'cadastrar'. Faça a alteração do ID ou troque para utilizar o `type`.

Veja seu código funcionando abaixo:

```js
function CPF() {
  "user_strict";

  function r(r) {
    for (var t = null, n = 0; 9 > n; ++n) t += r.toString().charAt(n) * (10 - n);
    var i = t % 11;
    return i = 2 > i ? 0 : 11 - i
  }

  function t(r) {
    for (var t = null, n = 0; 10 > n; ++n) t += r.toString().charAt(n) * (11 - n);
    var i = t % 11;
    return i = 2 > i ? 0 : 11 - i
  }
  this.gera = function() {
    for (var n = "", i = 0; 9 > i; ++i) n += Math.floor(9 * Math.random()) + "";
    var o = r(n),
      a = n + "-" + o + t(n + "" + o);
    return a
  }, this.valida = function(o) {
    for (var a = o.replace(/\D/g, ""), u = a.substring(0, 9), f = a.substring(9, 11), v = 0; 10 > v; v++)
      if ("" + u + f == "" + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v + v) return n;
    var c = r(u),
      e = t(u + "" + c);
    return f.toString() === c.toString() + e.toString()
  }
}

var CPF = new CPF();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cpf").keyup(function() {
    var teste = CPF.valida($(this).val());
    console.log(teste)
    $("#resposta").html(teste);
    if (teste) {
      $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled", true);
      console.log("O campo cpf é inválido! Preencha com um CPF válido por favor.");
    }
  });

  $("#cpf").blur(function() {
    var teste = CPF.valida($(this).val());
    $("#resposta").html(teste);
    if (teste) {
      $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled", false);;
    } else {
      console.log("O campo cpf é inválido! Preencha com um CPF válido por favor.");
      $("#cadastrar").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" /><span id="resposta"></span></p>
  <p><input id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" disabled /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Nossa o id cadastrar eu já tinha arrumado e mesmo assim não estava funcionando. vou verificar as alterações e posto aqui novamente se funcionou... valew man.

Comment: Nossa... isso mesmo que precisava... valew. Randrade.

Comment: Só modificou uma coisa que não sei resolver... Ao invés da resposta aparecer como CPF Válido ou inválido na span em frente ai input cpf está mostrando true ou false.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz a correção do seu código para que funcione da maneira correta.

```js
function ValidarCPF(strCPF) {
  var Soma;
  var Resto;
  strCPF = strCPF.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Permite apenas números
  Soma = 0;
  if (strCPF == "00000000000") return false;

  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
  Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

  if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
  if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(9, 10))) return false;

  Soma = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
  Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

  if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
  if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(10, 11))) return false;
  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cpf").blur(function() {
    var teste = ValidarCPF($(this).val());
    $("#resposta").html((teste ? 'Válido' : 'Inválido'));
    if (teste) {
      $("#cadastrar").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      alert("O campo cpf é inválido! Preencha com um CPF válido por favor.");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p><input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" /><span id="resposta"></span></p>
  <p><input id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" disabled /></p>
</form>
```