# Validar campo data de nascimento com javascript

Tags: javascript, validação, data

Tenho um campo do tipo `date`, com nome `txtdata_nasc`. Preciso de uma validação para ele. Preciso que tenha um botão do lado dele que o possa validar.

Se a pessoa digitar uma data de nascimento menor de 18 anos de idade, quero que apareça um `alert("Pessoas menores de 18 não podem se cadastrar.")`, e se ele digitar uma data de nascimento entre 18 e 60 anos, que apareça `alert("Maior de 18, pode se cadastrar.")`. A pessoa não pode colocar uma data que o faça ter mais de 60 anos.

Por favor, quero que tal código retorne em um botão com o `onclick='return validadata()'` como por exemplo.

Comment: Por que um botão do lado do campo ? Por que você não deixa simplesmente o botão de cadastrar e valida quando submeter ou então tenta utilizar jquery a função de foco no campo ao invés do botão, se fosse eu validaria com jquery muito mas fácil e prático visto que ele usa Ajax.

Comment: e como eu faria isso?

Comment: meu botão cadastrar é este:  <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btn1" onclick="return validacaodenome();"> só q ele já tem uma função como return, e eu não sei como faz pra usar mais de um return...

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/297935/132

Comment: [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5190/5043) pode te ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar esta função que verifica a idade de acordo com a data informada no `input` (explicações no código):

```js
function validadata(){
   var data = document.getElementById("nascimento").value; // pega o valor do input
   data = data.replace(/\//g, "-"); // substitui eventuais barras (ex. IE) "/" por hífen "-"
   var data_array = data.split("-"); // quebra a data em array
   
   // para o IE onde será inserido no formato dd/MM/yyyy
   if(data_array[0].length != 4){
      data = data_array[2]+"-"+data_array[1]+"-"+data_array[0]; // remonto a data no formato yyyy/MM/dd
   }
   
   // comparo as datas e calculo a idade
   var hoje = new Date();
   var nasc  = new Date(data);
   var idade = hoje.getFullYear() - nasc.getFullYear();
   var m = hoje.getMonth() - nasc.getMonth();
   if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoje.getDate() < nasc.getDate())) idade--;
   
   if(idade < 18){
      alert("Pessoas menores de 18 não podem se cadastrar.");
      return false;
   }

   if(idade >= 18 && idade <= 60){
      alert("Maior de 18, pode se cadastrar.");
      return true;
   }
   
   // se for maior que 60 não vai acontecer nada!
   return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="nascimento" id="nascimento">
<button type="button" onclick='return validadata()'>Validar</button>
```

Comment: precis da sua ajuda urgente no meu tcc mano, é o Pedro Vinicius aki

Comment: mano, tá dando uns erro na minha página de cadastro, que não consigo resolver, do nada parou de funcionar isso

Comment: você tem algum e-mail que eu possa te mandar a página?

Comment: mandei lá, o problema que está dando é na validação da data de nascimento, antes estava validando certinho, não pode menos de 18 anos e mais de 65, também está na senha, pois eu criei a variável para que possa usar apenas letras e números no campo, mas agora ele tá voltando o alert pra qualquer senha, e o CEP, peguei uma variável na internet para validá-lo, mas não funciona

Comment: achei alguns erros, no final tinha retornando as function naoNumerico em fora de ordem, ai ajeitei, mas msm assim a data ainda não tá funcionando nem a senha

Comment: to vendo aqui..

Comment: funcionou . . . . . . . . . ... . .. . . .

Comment: mas não tem campo de CEP.

Comment: <label for="inputText" class="sr-only">Bairro</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtCep" placeholder="CEP(Ex: #####-###)" class="form-control" maxlength="8" required />

Comment: Mais 2 coisas pra arrumar: `if (valida_senha || !senha) {` e `var padrao1 = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/gi;`

Comment: Coloquei bairro sem querer, ai mds desculpa

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79593/discussion-between-dvd-and-sdkamda2323).

Comment: Show, esse código salvou o dia, valeu