# Como eu faço para travar minha tela quando digita um CPF invalido?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um modal para digitar meu CPF, mas mesmo se eu colocar um CPF invalido e clicar no botão de avançar ele pula para a próxima tela, eu queria pular para a próxima tela só quando o CPF for valido

```
function CadastrarPessoa() {
    debugger
    var url = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Pessoa/VerificarUrl",
        data: {},

        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                //OpenModal('modal', '/Pessoa/AdicionarCliente');
                location.href = "/Pessoa/ClienteAlegriaCard";
            }
            else {
                debugger
                url = $("#VerificaCPF").val().length == 14 ? '/Pessoa/AdicionarPF' : '/Pessoa/AdicionarPJ'
                location.href = url
            }
        }

    });
}




$(document).on('focusout', '#VerificaCPF', function () {
    var cpf = $("#VerificaCPF").val();

    if (cpf.length >= 14) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pessoa/VerificaCpf/?cpf=' + cpf,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { cpf: cpf },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != false) {
                    if (data.IsFornecedor == false) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "/Pessoa/VerificarUrl",
                            data: {},
                            success: function (_data) {
                                if (_data == true) {
                                    $('#btnprx').attr('onclick', 'EditarClienteAlegriaCard(' + data.Id + ');');
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('#btnprx').attr('onclick', 'EditarPessoa(' + data.Id + ');');
                                }
                            }

                        });
                        $("#AdicionarNovo").hide();
                        $("#HasCliente").show()
                        $("#Nome").val(data.NmPessoa);
                        $("#Telefone").val(data.NuFone);
                        $("#Email").val(data.Email);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#btnprx').attr('onclick', 'CadatrarPessoa();');
                        $("#AdicionarNovo").hide();
                        $("#HasCliente").hide()
                        $("#Nome").val("");
                        $("#Telefone").val("");
                        $("#Email").val("");

                        noty({
                            text: "Cpf/Cnpj informado já possui cadastro de fornecedor!",
                            type: 'warning',
                            timeout: 3000,
                            layout: 'center'
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#HasCliente").hide()
                    $("#AdicionarNovo").show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: basta desabilitar o botão, usar uma função que valide, pode ser no `keypress`  do campo e habilitar o botão quando estiver ok

Comment: Eu consigo fazer isso tudo pelo javascript?

Comment: consegue sim... aproveite e veja essa pergunta que tem uma função de validação que pode ser usada pra validar o cpf: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51340/57220
o botão vc pode fazer um `$('#idDoBotao').attr('disabled','disabled')` para desabilitar, e para habilitar novamente remove o atributo: `$('#idDoBotao').attr('disabled','')`, pode ser feito com `prop()`, mas enfim basicamente é isso